# jQuery scrollstart, scrollstop and very quick scrolling issue

Tags: scroll, jquery, custom-events

I'm having an issue with [James Padolsey's custom events](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/): `scrollstart` and `scrolltop`

When I use the mouse wheel to scroll one "notch" or I click the scroll bar somewhere far below or above its current position, causing sudden scroll by a large amount, I get the same `scrollTop()` values for `scrollstart` and `scrolltop` - I can't tell where the scroll started or in which direction the scroll has taken place. jsFiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mLxE4/3/) (note: if you have an extremely high resolution, you will have to add more text to the HTML so that a scroll bar appears in the Result window).

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="scrollable">
            <!-- insert lots of text here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#scrollable {width: 120px;}
```

JavaScript:

```
var before = 0;

$(window).bind('scrollstart', function() {
    before = $(window).scrollTop();
});

$(window).bind('scrollstop', function() {
    alert('before: ' + before + "\nafter: " + $(window).scrollTop())
});
```

[jsFiddle available here](http://jsfiddle.net/mLxE4/3/)

Any ideas on how to retrieve the true `scrollTop()` value for the `scrollstart` event? Modifying the plugin is an option I guess, so all ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of recording the `before` value when the scroll starts, I would suggest doing so in another event, for example mousemove()

[jsFiddle of this idea working](http://jsfiddle.net/mLxE4/5/)

Comment: Nice idea, but fails if you use the mouse to drag the scroll bar

Comment: Still returns only the last few pixels of movement (0-5 depending on speed) in FF 10.0.2 when dragging the scrollbar with mouse

Comment: It must have something to do with the browser then, I am testing on Chrome and works fine. I don't have Firefox here so I can't tell, sorry

Comment: Indeed, seems different on different browsers. +1 for the effort, but hopefully there is a cross-browser solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your question (I haven't used that plugin), but I think you don't need to use every part of that plugin. If you only want to know the previous and current value of ScrollTop and its direction, take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/C3ye7/

```
var currentScrollTop, temporalScroll = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log('Previous value: ' + temporalScroll)
    if (currentScrollTop > temporalScroll) {
        console.log('scroll down')
        console.log('Current value: ' + currentScrollTop)
    }
    else { 
        console.log('scroll up');
        console.log('Current value: ' + currentScrollTop)
    }
    temporalScroll = currentScrollTop;

});
```

In order to add the timing functionality, you can use only that part of that plugin (or simply, start a setTimeout to record a bigger change when scrolling).

Comment: I changed alerts by console.log messages (I feel they're less annoying), so make sure to start your console to see the changes.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need the plugin's functionality of firing the `scrollstart` and `scrollstop` events

Comment: Well, you can still use that. Please notice that the actual plugin uses a timer: "... the only way to even simulate such an event would be to have a delay between the last scrolling action and the event itself – a timer could start on every “scroll” event and then if that timer is not cleared in time (say 500 milliseconds) then it can be assumed a user has “stopped scrolling”, or, has taken a break from a lengthy scroll; either circumstance warrants a “scrollstop” event in my opinion.".

Comment: I think what you describe is how the plugin actually works. Let me clear this up: I need to know when the scroll starts, when it ends and how far the user has scrolled. As far as I could tell, your solution reports on every scroll event (not what I'm after) and the scroll distance was minimal (difference between positions on consecutive scroll events; not what I'm after). If I'm missing something, do tell, because I still don't have a final solution and the bounty can still be awarded :) Cheers

Comment: You're right in your assessments but what I told you was that you could implement detection of when a scroll starts, particularly when you already have the start, end and distance in between of every scroll event. You can implement this by using a timer to avoid recording every scroll event by using the idea (and code, if you want) explained in the plugin's page.

Comment: OK, it may be too early in the morning for me to comprehend, so sorry if I'm asking dumb questions. So your idea is to rewrite the plugin to do the exact same thing as it already does? Or what?

Comment: Not rewrite the plugin because it doesn't do what you want. Anyway, I feel you don't need 'scrollstart' and 'scrolltop' from the plugin as they're giving you problems. That's why I suggested implementing the same functionality without the plugin. It is simple enough to be a viable option.